# React Page not showing when using Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am linking Navbar pages to their correct buttons. I followed documents and when I ran the code, it showed me a blank screen. I think it is my `Route` and `Routes` component that is causing this, and when ran with just the `<Navbar />` the `Navbar` loads but when I include `<Route>` it switches to a blank screen.
I made a simple `App.js` component for the `Navbar`

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar'
import Home from './Components/Home'
import About from './Components/About'
import { BrowserRouter , Routes ,  Route,   } from 'react-router-dom'

import React from 'react'
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar'
import Home from './Components/Home'
import About from './Components/About'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={ <Home/> } />
        <Route path='about' element={ <About/> } />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App;
```

And my index.js too

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <>
    <App />
  </>
);
```

When ran it just gave me a blank white page, I have made sure that all of my links and imports are correct. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Just to confirm your index.html has a `<div id="root" />`? Are there any errors in console?

Comment: I don't see any overt issue in the code you've shared. Can you [edit] the post to include the components you are trying to render? Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces any issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: There are multiple things that seem off. Double importing, rendering app in `<Fragment>`, we don't know how your components are exported what URI are you connecting to and I think it should be `/about`

Answer (score 0):

your routes seem to be correct. I don't understand why you import things twice, but referring to your problem, i think the problem is in your components.

You can see devTools console when show blank page and comment if show an error. If don't, it's probably because it doesn't render anything.